# Extract text from HTML using Applescript

Tags: macos, html, applescript, code

I am looking to extract text from an html using Applescript, here is the code:

```
<div class="vk_bk vk_ans">3:27 PM</div>
```

I want to extract "3:27 PM" which is the result google gives you when you ask the time in New York. Google will always give you a direct result between those tags and i am looking to extract it and once extracted exported to a .txt. If you guys need more of the HTML just search time in New York and inspect the element.

All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's easy to extract using `sed` command on the terminal.

```
sed -E 's/<div class="vk_bk vk_ans">(.*)<\/div>/\1/g' filename
```

This will return you the text between `<div class="vk_bk vk_ans">` and `</div>` that exists on your `filename`.

Comment: I copied and pasted all of the html onto a .txt file and enter the command you told me on terminal which is: sed -E 's/<div class="vk_bk vk_ans">(.*)<\/div>/\1/g' test.txt. but i get all of the html back once i inserted the command. Please Help!